# Recursive query with loop counter

Tags: mysql, select, recursion

In MySQL I have the following `object` table:

```
| id | parent_id | name |
|---:|----------:|:-----|
|  1 |      NULL | root |
|  2 |         9 | obj1 |
|  3 |        10 | obj2 |
|  4 |         7 | obj3 |
|  5 |         8 | obj4 |
|  6 |         4 | obj5 |
|  7 |         2 | obj6 |
|  8 |         3 | obj7 |
|  9 |         1 | obj8 |
| 10 |         1 | obj9 |
```

And the following Query to get a path from my element (id 6) to root:

```
SELECT  @id :=
        (
        SELECT  parent_id
        FROM    object
        WHERE   id = @id
        ) AS tree
FROM    (
        SELECT  @id := 6
        ) a
STRAIGHT_JOIN object
WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
```

The result is:

```
| tree |
|-----:|
|    4 |
|    7 |
|    2 |
|    9 |
|    1 |
| NULL |
```

But I need a counter in the result, that represents the travertion through the path (like a counter in a for-loop):

```
| tree | ctr |
|-----:|----:|
|    4 |   1 |
|    7 |   2 |
|    2 |   3 |
|    9 |   4 |
|    1 |   5 |
| NULL |   6 |
```

Is it possible to add the counter and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your query is guaranteed to work, but it might (between the `straight join` and subquery, the order of execution might be guaranteed).  You can get a counter by using another variable:

```
SELECT  @id := (SELECT parent_id
                FROM object
                WHERE id = @id
               ) AS tree,
        (@rn := @rn + 1) as ctr
FROM (SELECT  @id := 6, @rn := 0) a STRAIGHT_JOIN
     object
WHERE @id IS NOT NULL;
```